# Filtering a List of SelectListItem to create list SelectList with unique values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to filter out items from the select list if they are already in the list of items belonging to a particular entity.
So if an entity already has an item, the item wont be available to choose from in the list.

Error in code below:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>`

```
 //list of subject areas belonging to a specific course
 public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> SubjectAreas { get; set; } = new 
 List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

 //list of all subject areas available
 public List<SelectListItem> SubjectAreasForDropdown { get; set; }

 //the below throw the error mentioned above
 SubjectAreasForDropdown.ForEach(
     a => a.Selected = SubjectAreas
     .Contains(Convert.ToInt32(a.Value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

SubjectAreas is a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`

When you do contains, It will check for a KeyValuePair Object, where you are supplying int.

I feel you need to use
a => a.Selected = SubjectAreas[Convert.ToInt32(a.Value)]

Also could you brief what are you trying to acheive

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>' to 'bool'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a => a.Selected = SubjectAreas.Any(x=>x.Key == Convert.ToInt32(a.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks but whilst this has no errors it doesn't give the desired result. The goal is to only choose elements for the select list that aren't contained in subjectAreas

Comment: After ForEach, you can use Selected == false to find all not exists item. Have you try?